# Showing this sum is absolutely convergent using the ratio test.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

I'm trying to show that $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n \, x^{2n+1}}{2^n\,n!}$ is absolutely convergent for all $x$.
Using the ratio test I get:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\dfrac{f_{n+1}(x)}{f_n(x)}\right| = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1} \, x^{2n+3}}{2^{n+1} \, (n+1)!}\; \dfrac{2^n \, n!}{(-1)^n \, x^{2n+1}}\right|$

This simplifies to:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\dfrac{x^2}{2 \, (n+1)}\right|$

Now if $x \to \infty$, this limit won't be less than 1, right?

However, on the internet I found some pages saying the considered sum absolutely converges for all $x$ $\implies$ radius of convergence is $\infty$.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: The limit is being taken as $n\to \infty$ and not as $x\to \infty$.

Comment: Yeah, but does it hold true for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Yes, for **every** $x$, the limit of the ratios is zero.

Comment: Alright, thank you